# SharePoint - How do I change senders email address from "User Name <no-reply@sharepointonline.com>"

Tags: email, sharepoint

Here is the problem:

Sharepoint was working fine on and before the 9th of December, 2022.
And by this, I mean and still want to be able to have use of the ability for the internal users of our Business Premium 365 accounts to send file or folder share notifications to external users.  Where these share notification emails are from the sender's outlook account associated with their Sharepoint account, with the correct sender's name and email address.
Also, these emails were stored in the internal user's sent items folder.

Perfect!

UNTIL after the 9th of December 2022, something changed, and we have no idea what.

The change is that now the process still works, but the sender's email address has been changed to no-reply@sharepointonline.com.

And these share notification emails are no longer stored within the user's outlook sent items folder, these share notification emails now appear in the sender's inbox from SharePoint.

We are sharing SharePoint files and folders with our customers and we are now receiving a huge amount of calls asking where these notifications have gone.  Although we have sent them.  We have to explain to our customers that this change from SharePoint has meant that any share notification emails we send may now be in there spam or junk systems.

THIS IS QUITE UNACCEPTABLE - ESPECIALLY WITHOUT PRIOR WARNING THAT THIS WAS GOING TO HAPPEN.

And please, please, please do not tell me that Microsoft sent us notifications in 2016 warning us that this would happen.  It's 2022/2023 and it's only just happened!

This leads me to believe that this feature change is something temporary and or recent within SharePoint.

Can anyone shed some sensible light on this issue and give me some peace of mind that Microsoft is still not in the habit of changing things in live platforms and then hiding under their desks?

Help please, my sanity is waning!!!

Answer (score 1):

As of July 2023, there's now a way to customize the *send-from* address.

Just open [this URL](https://admin.microsoft.com/adminportal/?#/Settings/OrganizationProfile/:/Settings/L1/SendFromAddressSettings), or browse through this:

*Microsoft 365 admin center > (Show all) > Settings > Org settings > Organization profile > Send email notifications from your domain*

Enable the "Use a custom send-from domain address" and insert "no-reply" or whatever you want, from your actual domain. It's not needed for the email address to exist as a mailbox, but you can choose a real one if you wish.

[image: Microsoft 365 admin center screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never, almost a month later, Microsoft replied:

> Thank you for your patience on this.
> We advise that a fix for this has been recently rolled out and completed last night.
> Please can you try replicating the issue again and let me know if the same behaviour occurs.

So they fixed it, and let me know - there is a first!!!

My apologies for wasting peoples time.

Comment: So, they fixed this for your specific organization, very odd. I have the same problem and any solution is welcome, even if I need to create a ticket. Can you give us some more detail about how you contacted support (e.g. ticket URL, text)?